# jQuery AJAX Download file contents to String

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get the response of an API that returns JSON.
My current code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://blockchain.info/address/1BmqgMppdofEbVAKTkxsJ9N6JvFXmySEQk?format=json",
    success : function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

But this code does nothing, and I never get the alert

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the proper way to do this? This code doesn't do anything

Comment: You `result` in `success` itself is response from `api`.. May be you are not getting response from `api`..

Comment: I don't even get the alert

Comment: There can be several problems in your code: 1) cross-origin request; 2) ajax raises error and not success; 3) jQuery is not included in the page, etc.

Comment: i have jQuery included, and what can I do about that Cross Origin thing?

Comment: **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.** check the console for errors.

Comment: But when I type this url into the addres bar of my browser, I can see the JSON response

Comment: @LórántGerber Sure but server doesn't allow you to use its own content on your own page, that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cross domain issue:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://blockchain.info/address/1BmqgMppdofEbVAKTkxsJ9N6JvFXmySEQk?format=json. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

You need to create separate server side script (PHP?) witch get content for You and passes to Your script. And then query it.

For example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/address/1BmqgMppdofEbVAKTkxsJ9N6JvFXmySEQk?format=json');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must dataType : json inside ajax like this,

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://blockchain.info/address/1BmqgMppdofEbVAKTkxsJ9N6JvFXmySEQk",
    dataType: "json", 
    success : function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I still don't get the alert

Comment: @LórántGerber paste your console response here.

Comment: HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
gerberloci13.xyz
HTML1506: Unexpected token.
gerberloci13.xyz (29,1)
SEC7120: Origin http://gerberloci13.xyz not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
gerberloci13.xyz
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.
gerberloci13.xyz

Answer (score 0):

**detailed error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://blockchain.info/address/1BmqgMppdofEbVAKTkxsJ9N6JvFXmySEQk?format=json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).**

```
.add header in requested resource file header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: This would be a solution if OP was owning the server API which is obviously not the case